# Get array values from specific index with specified length

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am doing some code challenge and I want to get the first 3 values from my array by specifying the starting index and getting only the first (3 or can be any length) values from the starting index.

I tried this code and it is working but the code structure is too long so how can I make this shorter so it can be easy to understand.

```cs
            int n = 10;
            double signature = new double[] { 1, 1, 1 };
            double[] ret = new double[n];
            double sum = 0;
            ret[0] = signature[0];
            ret[1] = signature[1];
            ret[2] = signature[2];
            int x, i;

            for (i = 0; i < n - signature.Length; i++)
            {
                for(x = i; x <= signature.Length + i; x++)
                {
                    sum += ret[x];
                }
                ret[x - 1] = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }

            return ret;
```

Comment: Your current code doesn't seem to do what you currently describe in your question text. Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your question. Are you trying to calculte some sort of sum of three elements over a moving starting index ?

Comment: FWIW, how did you decide that Linq is going to give you performance ? It gives you readability and in other cases lazy read, but in the example you have shown, i don't think Linq is going to make the program run any faster.

Comment: @John I just wanted my code to be more shorter.

Comment: @RomainVergnory yes!! and its already working I'm just looking for simpler approach.

Comment: @Soundararajan oh Im not really not sure for what I've said I just thought that the shorter the code the faster it will be executed.

Comment: @John thats why Im asking sir and I just showed what I have, by reading the code you can see that I based the index and length of the array by using the for loop method when I can actually do simpler approach.

Comment: Since this question is about code that works, but can be improved, would the question fit better on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) than on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @jkdev You're right, I am new in stack overflow and taking my time to fully understand every part of it and this is the first time I saw Code Review. I'll use Code Review next time if it comes to this kind of things thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ you can try something like this:

```
var values = array.Skip(index)
                  .Take(n)
                  .ToArray();
```

Where `index` is the index of the first item and `n` the number of the items you want to pick.

E.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pk1rwY

As a side note. Using LINQ does not mean that your code would be faster. It would be more compact/readable etc. In order you assess how performant is your code you have to use something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for thanks!!!

Comment: @Keith You are very welcome. I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 3):

No *Linq* solution:

```
private static T[] Extract<T>(T[] source, int fromIndex, int length) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  else if (fromIndex < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(fromIndex), 
                                         "From Index must be non-negative");
  else if (length < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), 
                                         "Length must be non-negative");

  if (fromIndex >= source.Length || length == 0)
    return new T[0];

  T[] result = new T[Math.Min(length, source.Length - fromIndex)];

  Array.Copy(source, fromIndex, result, 0, result.Length);

  return result;
}
```

Then

```
 double[] signature = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 double[] ret = Extract(signature, 3, 2);

 Console.Write(string.Join(", ", ret));
```

Outcome:

```
 3, 4
```

Comment: Thanks but is it really better to use a non linq solution?

Comment: @Keith: it's faster (Linq will create `IEnuemrable<T>`, intermediate `List<T>` etc., say, it can be useful if you want to extract 1 million items from 1 billion array); I've added validation as well: if `source`, `fromIndex`, `length` are invalid you have a readable exception

Answer (score 2):

From your question, you need to take advantage of the operators `.Take` and `.Skip`.

```cs
   var result = array.Skip(startingIndex).Take(numberOfElements);
```

From your code thus, it seems you're trying to do something a bit different, namely summing elements. The `.Sum` operator might be of help here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to use the .Sum operator. :))